# javascript getSelection give me value twice

Tags: javascript

here is my question.I am developing a translation chrome extension,and I want that the yellow page shows and gives me the translation when I select word.

this is my code

```
var txt = null;

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log("upbf    txt:" + txt);
  txt = funGetSelectTxt(); //get Select word
  console.log("up    txt:" + txt);

  if (check(txt)) {
    mydivm.style.display = "block";
    //translate and show
  }
};

document.onmousedown = function(e) {
  txt = "";
  var mydivm = document.getElementById("fgbnbb");

  if (mydivm.style.display == "block") {
    if (!isinclude(e, mydivm)) {
      mydivm.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  console.log("down  txt:" + txt);
};

var funGetSelectTxt = function() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection();
  } 
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    return document.getSelection();
  } 
  else {
    var selection = document.selection && 
    document.selection.createRange();

    if (selection.text) {
      return selection.text;
    }

    return false;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Well,the question is,if I select a word in the html tag `<p>` or some other,it work well,but if I select a html tag `<text>`,it has some problem.

the first I selected,the page show and down well,then I click on the text,it show again(in my wish,it will hide),and in the three time,it hide.

I don't know why.[the console log in the three time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpL9L.png), I want know why and how to solve that .

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. Please, follow the rules of typing in the future.

Comment: You should add also the HTML you're using